# How to use spring filters to impersonate user after CAS login

Tags: spring-security, cas

Is there a spring filter object that will allow me to choose which authentication token to pass on through the spring security chain.

I want to examine the httpsession and choose between using the token generated by the CAS filter or one i generate from the httpsession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the following:

1)  Override CasAuthenticationFilter

2)  Implements your own attemptAuthentication method (below)

3) Configure your filter

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
       throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
    // Access to HTTP request
    if (it CAS authentication) {
        return  super.attemptAuthentication(request,response);
    } else {
        // provide username, password
       final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
       authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
       return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Michael. I had the same idea. Unfortunately our application is using a **org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter** rather than a **org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter**. And the jasig filter is final. I am in the process of swapping the one out with the other so that I can implement this solution.